# Is there 1 SYCL implementation to rule all platforms?

Tags: c++, gpu, nvidia, sycl

Apologies for the slightly jokey title, but I couldn't find another way to concisely describe the question. I work in a team that use predominantly OpenCL code with a CPU fallback. For the most part this works fine, except when it comes to Nvidia and their refusal to use SPIR-V for OpenCL.

I recently found and have been looking into SYCL, but the ecosystem surrounding it is more than a little bit confusing, and in one case I found one implementation referring to using another implementation.

So my question is: is there a single SYCL implementation that can produce a single binary that has runtime support for Nvidia, AMD and Intel (preferred, but not required) and either x64 or Arm64 (we would create a second binary for the other one) without having to do what we do now which is select a bunch of GPUs from the various vendors build the kernels for each one separately and then have to ship them all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2022, for Linux and x86_64:

- The [open-source version of DPC++](https://github.com/intel/llvm/) can compile code for all three GPU vendors. In my experience, a single binary for all three vendors works.
- [hipSYCL](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL/) has official support for NVIDIA and AMD devices, and experimental support for Intel GPUs (via the above-mentioned DPC++).

> without having to do what we do now which is select a bunch of GPUs from the various vendors build the kernels for each one separately and then have to ship them all.

Note: Under the hood, both hipSYCL and DPC++ work this way. The kernels are compiled to PTX, GCN, and/or SPIR-V. They are bundled into a single binary, though, so, in this respect, the distribution can be simpler (or not: you will likely have to also ship the SYCL runtime libraries with your application).

Comment: hipSYCL also supports compiling to one binary for all GPU vendors :)

And once https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL/pull/862 is merged, hipSYCL will be able to target Intel GPUs without going through any DPC++ code paths AND have a unified kernel code representation for all backends. So it will no longer have to compile and embed kernels for PTX, GCN, SPIR-V etc separately, making it more extensible, and leading to faster compile times.

hipSYCL also supports arm as offload host, and any LLVM-supported CPU (including arm, x86) as execution target for kernels.